# Refer to pandas dataframe columns or index, depending on parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a function that operates on the labels of a pandas dataframe and I want to have a parameter `axis` to decide whether to operate on index or columns.

So I wrote something like:

```
if axis==0:
    to_sort = df.index
elif axis==1:
    to_sort = df.columns
else:
    raise AttributeError
```

where `df` is a pandas dataframe.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Note I am not asking for a code review, but more specifically asking if there is a pandas attribute (something like `labels` would make sense to me) that allows me to get index or columns depending on a parameter/index to be passed.

For example (code not working):

```
df.labels[0]   # index
df.labels[1]   # columns
```

Comment: Any suggestion for a better title is well accepted

Comment: what is wrong with `.index` and `.columns` ? You can use them only na

Comment: Nothing is wrong but...at the end of this code I am assigning the transformed labels. Then I would have again to do an if/else as above.
So I was just wondering if there was a parametrized way of referring to index or columns to avoid this repetitions.

Comment: Why not use a function to do the task ? `def labels(df,param) :` and then `labels(df,param)`. Current both of them are not made one object as of I know.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can use `iloc(axis=...)`

Documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

> You can also specify the axis argument to .loc to interpret the passed
>   slicers on a single axis.

(They seem to have omitted `iloc` in regards to the `axis` parameter)

## A complete example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['a1', 'a2'], "B":['b1', 'b2']})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0  a1  b1
1  a2  b2
```

### With axis=0

```
print(df.iloc(axis=0)[0].index)
```

Output:

```
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

### With axis=1

```
print(df.iloc(axis=1)[0].index)
```

Output:

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)
```

Comment: How sure are you with `iloc` ? It aint meant for getting index and columns. You are selecting the data with iloc. You may have to use `.index` at the end.

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood your question. I thought the output is what you are after. Or are you saying it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Well if you understand the question, what OP asked is to provide an altenative for `.index` and `.columns` in the form of one object to provide both. So if you use iloc it will give data by setting the specific axis as index. So you might have to use `df.iloc(axis=1)[0].index` to give what OP asked.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, I've updated it. Although I realise the meaning of axis is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) documentation examples, I realized I can do something like this:

- Let the parameter be `axis`={'index', 'columns'}
- Get the relevant labels using `getattr`:   `labels = getattr(df, axis)`

Open to other pandas specific solutions.
If I were forced to use `axis={1, 0}`, then @Bharath suggestion to use an helper function makes sense.